# Git: Deployment to a Production Server

Tags: git

I have a Windows server with a library consisting of scripts written in a vendor's proprietary scripting language. In addition to the vendor (who intermittently issues new releases of the core system), we have a small team of developers who make custom mods to the library. Our custom mods go in an override folder so we don't have to worry about collisions with the vendor's mods.

I've been tasked with getting the library into a source control solution. My only constraint is that the code cannot be hosted off-site. I'm looking at Git.

So if I understand things correctly, I should set up a public repository in a location somewhere (either on this box or another box in our network) and the developers can clone from there.

Then I checkout from that repo into our current production folders.  Yes?

So here's my noob question:
This server is where the scripts execute, so I have to be able to state unequivocally that installing GIT on this server is not going to impact the existing system.

Is that a safe statement to make?

If not, or if this is not the way to go, is there some sort of deployment tool I can use to copy mods out of the public repo to our production folders?

Thanks in advance and my apologies if my understanding of GIT is 100% wrong.

JP

Comment: git is just file system snapshots.  Anything else but that needs to be taken care of by something else.

Comment: Note that if you are setting up a central git server, possibly with permissions, you probably want some SW to manage that. [gitlolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) is a very lightweight and robust infrastructure to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a safe statement to make. A git client will not affect the rest of the system. The only folders git has permission to modify is the folders in which you clone or create a git repository.

Here's a link with some answers on the subject for you to read about: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45452/is-using-git-for-deploying-a-bad-practice.